# Spring WebFlux detect client disconnect

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, flux, server-sent-events

Suppose the following `@RestController`:

```
@GetMapping("listen")
public Flux<Object> listen() {
    return Flux.create(sink -> process(sink));
}
```

And somewhere

```
sink.next(new Object());
```

This code has no information about sink state or completion

Tried using `isCanceled`, it returns false every time.

Is it possible to detect is `FluxSink` is still being used by the client?

Comment: FluxSink has an `isCancelled` method. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @martin-tarjányi yes, but after client closes connection sink didn't cancel. Docs say nothing about it.

Comment: Did you figure it out? @JEY's solution does nothing for me if I send a GET request to the server (application/stream+json) with CURL and then cancel it (on client side).

Comment: @Peter I don't remember why, but I ended up manually canceling flux after fixed period of time and force client to reconnect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spring-webflux if the client close the connection the subscription will be canceled and  disposed.
If in the process method you add a callback onCancel and onDispose you will see that.

```
private <T> void process(final FluxSink<T> sink) {
    sink.onCancel(new Disposable() {
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            System.out.println("Flux Canceled");
        }
    });

    sink.onDispose(new Disposable() {

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            System.out.println("Flux dispose");
        }
    });
}
```

Then send an http request to your endpoint and cancel it before your flux complete. You will see that both callbacks are triggered.

Comment: This does not work for me, the dispose methods are not reached. Any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: Just did a quick test with the following https://gist.github.com/Julien-Eyraud/0c7413790c57919575cc4ffae6239850 If i do a curl http://localhost:8080 and terminate it I can see the Flux Canceled and Flux dispose. Same thing when I open it in firefox and close the tab.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with netty configuration. Try to had a ReadTimeoutHandler or set server.netty.connection-timeout. But in my test case no need for this kind of configuration

Comment: thanks for your response - I use tomcat, can this be the problem?

Comment: this is possible. I never tried webflux with anything else than netty. Maybe you can tweek tomcat timeouts. But not sure about the result

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer is only work combined with "sever send event", the server send periodical event to client, when the client is disconnected the subscription will be canceled. as the document says https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-streaming